# How to dispatch a multimethod on the type of an array

Tags: clojure

I'm working on a multimethod that needs to update a hash for a bunch of different things in a sequence. Looked fairly straitforward until I tried to enter the 'type of an array of X'.

```
(defmulti update-hash #(class %2))

(type (byte 1))
=> java.lang.Byte
(defmethod update-hash java.lang.Byte [md byte]
  (. md update byte))

(type (into-array  [ (byte 1)]))
=> [Ljava.lang.Byte;
(defmethod update-hash < WHAT GOES HERE > [md byte]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either of these should work:

```
(defmethod update-hash (Class/forName "[Ljava.lang.Byte;") [md byte] ...)

(defmethod update-hash (class (make-array Byte 0)) [md byte] ... )
```

Comment: where does the name "[Ljava.lang.Byte;" come from?

Comment: It's some name the JVM uses internally to refer to arrays.  You'll see it in plain Java sometimes too.