# Java arrays in Clojure's gen-interface

Tags: clojure

I have this piece of code:

```
(ns com.example.main)

(gen-class
  :name com.example.main.CTest
  :methods [ [foo [] "[B"]])

(defn -foo [this]
  (byte-array [(byte 1) (byte 2)]))

(gen-interface
  :name com.example.main.ITest
  :methods [ [foo [] "[B"]])
```

It creates the `foo` method in class `CTest` correctly, with return type `byte[]`. However, the same thing creates a method with return type `[B` in the `ITest` interface. How do I do this correctly? Is it a bug in Clojure?

Thanks, David

Comment: a [related question here][1], except about multimethods instead of gen-interface


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782901/how-to-dispatch-a-multimethod-on-the-type-of-an-array

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if some other solution is preferred, but this works:

```
(gen-interface
  :name com.example.main.ITest
  :methods [[foo [] #=(java.lang.Class/forName "[B")]])
```